# Heroku-like Amazon EC2

Tags: heroku, amazon-web-services

Is there anything that I can install on my EC2 instances that make AWS Heroku-like?

e.g:

- heroku create app
- git push

But for AWS.

Comment: Doesn't *Heroku* make AWS Heroku-like?

Comment: Yes, but I still want to use AWS and not Heroku

Comment: As Thomas Anthony has touched on: setting up an AWS instance to be "like Heroku" would essentially involve rolling a lot from scratch. You'll need to write pre-receive and post-receive hooks for Git (after installing Git and setting it up), set up the web servers and relevant language support, databases, etc. There's a lot of work to it if you're inexperienced, and if you're asking the question in the first place chances are there is a lot of learning to do first.

Comment: You may want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10112211/self-hosted-alternatives-to-heroku

Answer (score 7):

Well, now there is! It's called [AWS Elastic Beanstalk](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/) (still in beta, as of March 2013)

After running the initial setup, further deployments should be as simple as `git aws.push`

**EDIT:** Just a nice and broad overview of deployment possibilities at AWS, by [Werner Vogels](http://www.allthingsdistributed.com/2013/02/aws-opsworks.html) (AWS CTO):

[image]

Comment: Well, git aws.push works well, however works with Beanstalk only. Also please take into account that beanstalk is pre-configured container, where you have limited control on instance software, scripts etc.

Comment: @JohnBeynon As Amazon says in their doc, AWS OpsWorks will be more "DevOps automation" whereas AWS Beanstalk would be more "developers friendly", I've updated the answer with a better illustration.

Answer (score 1):

There are few topics I need to touch on before I can answer your question thoroughly; so please, bear with me.

### A bit of insight

With respects to your two examples, Heroku utilizes a number of different technologies in order to achieve the level of simplicity it provides as a service platform. One of these technologies include: Heroku's proprietary toolbelt, which offers a set of command-line tools —that allows developers to interface with their applications— and an interact with many of the tools Heroku provides —such as terminal access for a number of different languages. The toolbelt itself relies on two other technologies: Ruby and Git; which come prepackaged with the install.

### In a nutshell

Now, when you create a Heroku app you are effectively creating a git repository on the celedon cedar runtime stack (by default); this repository is then added as a remote repo. This allows you to immediately run `git push heroku master`. There is a lot more happening behind the scenes: for instance, when you push, your commits get intercepted by a git pre-receive hook which runs your app through a slug compiler and prepackages it for distribution across the dyno manifold; yet, I digress. For more information on more advance topics, check-out: https://devcenter.heroku.com/; there is a wealth of information here to read.

### The stack

Now, let me explain the cedar stack as this is mainly what your question concerns. The Celedon cedar is one of many; however, this is the current default (for many reasons). This polyglot runtime stack currently provides six web languages (at the time of writing,) running on Ubuntu (11.04 stable, I belive). All of these technologies are operating on top of the AWS EC2 computing environment.

So to finally answer your question: You will need to install a suitable operating system such like: Ubuntu; a set of languages such like: Ruby, Python, Node.js, etc; Git (for deployment) and the rest is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have fixed number of instances make sense instead of usage Elastic Beanstalk use custom git deployment, like described in the article: http://www.jeffhoefs.com/2012/09/setup-git-deploy-for-aws-ec2-ubuntu-instance/.

Main idea to setup GIT repository on EC2 instance. When you want to deploy something just push your changes to remote repository, installed on EC2 instance.

I think this approach have next benefits in comparison with Elastic Beanstalk:

1. You don't pay for S3 buckets for storing application versions;
2. You have full control on application deployment steps.